# Regex match and replace

Tags: regex

I need to match only the **start** of string like these with mainly pattern in **"KEYWORD AAA/0010/0 "** with a space after **/0** and replace it with any other string. It has to happen for only the instance in the start.

```
KEYWORD AAA/0010/0 
KEYWORD AAAAAA/0010/0
KEYWORD AAA/001000/0
KEYWORD AAA/0010/000
KEYWORD AAA/0010/0 Testing comment
KEYWORD AAA/0010/0 Testing comment KEYWORD AAA/0010/0 Testing comment
KEYWORD */*/*
KEYWORD ?/?/?
```

I have tried this but it does not distinguish between the instances at start and middle and it does not match the last one

```
^KEYWORD .*\/.*\/.*\s
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear which exact part of the expression you are trying to match in order to replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
^KEYWORD [^\s/]*\/[^\s/]*\/[^\s/]*(?:\s|$)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?3348v)

The last row is not matched, because there is no space following, therefore I replaced it by Whitespace or the end of the string `(?:\s|$)`.

Answer (score 1):

Ungreedy `.*?`'s (match until next `/`, or even `[^/]*`), and optional `\s` with `\s?` (for the last line), making `^KEYWORD .*?\/.*?\/.*?\s?` or `^KEYWORD [^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\s?`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're almost there. Your regex isn't matching your last test case because there isn't a space at the end. Try this instead:

```
/^KEYWORD .*\/.*\/.*(\s|$)/
```

Comment: This one almost works but it matches all instances, not only the first instance in a line. May be my question was not clear. +1